# Compare element in a vector with elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, vector

I have two data structures with data in them.

- One is a vector `std::vector<int> presentStudents` And other is a
- `char` array `char cAllowedStudents[256];`

Now I have to compare these two such that checking every element in `vector` against the `array` such that all elements in the vector should be present in the array or else I will return `false` if there is an element in the vector that's not part of the array.

I want to know the most efficient and simple solution for doing this. I can convert my `int vector` into a `char array` and then compare one by one but that would be lengthy operation. Is there some better way of achieving this?

Comment: Are the collections sorted? What is the length of the `char` array, we know the size of 256.

Comment: Although I provided the answer which I personally believe is most efficient in your case, there is one general thing I'd like to mention: While efficiency is always good when it comes for free, it should be at the very bottom of your priority list if this is really only about 256 students. As long as this function is not called inside a huge loop, I believe code clarity and maintainability should be much more important in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort `cAllowedstudents` using `std::sort`.
2. Iterate over the `presentStudents` and look for each student in the sorted `cAllowedStudents` using `std::binary_search`.
3. If you don't find an item of the vector, return false.
4. If all the elements of the vector are found, return true.

Here's a function:

```
bool check()
{
   // Assuming hou have access to cAllowedStudents
   // and presentStudents from the function.

   char* cend = cAllowedStudents+256;
   std::sort(cAllowedStudents, cend);

   std::vector<int>::iterator iter = presentStudents.begin();
   std::vector<int>::iterator end = presentStudents.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      if ( !(std::binary_search(cAllowedStudents, cend, *iter)) )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Another way, using `std::difference`.

```
bool check()
{
   // Assuming hou have access to cAllowedStudents
   // and presentStudents from the function.

   char* cend = cAllowedStudents+256;
   std::sort(cAllowedStudents, cend);

   std::vector<int> diff;
   std::set_difference(presentStudents.begin(), presentStudents.end(),
                       cAllowedStudents, cend,
                       std::back_inserter(diff));
   return (diff.size() == 0);
}
```

Comment: why not use something like `std::set_difference`?

Comment: @billz std::set_difference would work too. It will do the same computation but will also create another container.

Comment: @R Sahu: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `binary_serach` doesn't return an iterator, but a boolean. So the comparison with cend should not be necessary.

Comment: @billz: I like the `set::difference` version as it is very compact. What I don't like about `set_difference` however, is that (as far as the standard is concerned) it doesn't use the (in-)equality operator but uses the less operator two times. Do you know if this is optimized away in actual implementations?

Comment: @MikeMB You are correct about the return value of `binary_search`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think there would be comparision also.. as my array if of `char` and vector contains `int`?

Comment: @Maven If you mean conversion, then this may depend on your architecture but on an x86 PC I'd expect this conversion to be a NOP. Btw.: Any algorithm proposed here has this "problem"

Comment: yes my bad i meant `conversion` and I am on `x64`PC and the compiler is giving me this error: `error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'char *' to 'int'
` and `error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'`

Comment: `if ( !(std::binary_search(cAllowedStudents, cend, *iter)) )
` Here.

Comment: @Maven sounds like a typo in your code. I believe you are passing variables of type `char**` as the first two arguments to binary_search. How do you pass the array to the `check` function (what is the signature of your check function)?

Comment: `char cAllowedStudents[256];` This is my array and i am inserting records into it form database.

Comment: @maven what i meant was that if yoz have copied the solution you had to make the array available inside the function `check()`. Did Ou do this by making the aray a global varable or by passing it as a parameter to `check`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a hash map ([std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)). Store all the elements of the char array in the hash map.

Then simply sequentially check each element in your vector whether it is present in the map or not in O(1).

```
Total time complexity O(N), extra space complexity O(N).
```

Note that you will have to enable C++11 in your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to function set_difference() in c++ algorithm header file. You can use this function directly, and check if result diff set is empty or not. If not empty return false.

A better solution would be adapting the implementation of set_difference(), like in here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference, to return false immediately after you get first different element.

Example adaption:

```
while (first1 != last1)
{
    if (first2 == last2) 
        return false;

    if (*first1 < *first2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (*first2 == *first1)
        {
            ++first1;
        }
        ++first2;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort both lists with std::sort and use std::find iteratively on the array.

EDIT: The trick is to use the previously found position as a start for the next search.

```
std::sort(begin(pS),end(pS))
std::sort(begin(aS),end(aS))

auto its=begin(aS);
auto ite=end(aS);

for (auto s:pS) {
    its=std::find(its,ite,s);
    if (its == ite) {
        std::cout << "Student not allowed" << std::cout;
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit: As legends mentiones, it usually might be more efficient to use binary search (as in R Sahu's answer). However, for small arrays and if the vector contains a significant fraction of students from the array (I'd say at least one tenths), the additional overhead of binary search might (or might not) outweight its  asymptotic complexity benefits.

Comment: That would be inefficient, isn't it? Why use `std::find` when the they are sorted?

Comment: The array might be a superset of the numbers in the vector. Also you can start the search woth the position of the last found element. This way you achieve linear complexety after the lists are sorted.

Comment: @legends2k but i admit, for such a short list, a simple bruteforce search for all elements might be even more efficient

Answer (score -1):

Using C++11. In your case, `size` is 256. Note that I personally have not tested this, or even put it into a compiler. It should, however, give you a good idea of what to do yourself. I HIGHLY recommend testing the edge cases with this!

```
#include <algorithm>

bool check(const std::vector<int>& studs, 
char* allowed, 
unsigned int size){

    for(auto x : studs){
        if(std::find(allowed, allowed+size-1, x) == allowed+size-1 && x!= *(allowed+size))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```