# Converting a char array into an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I have a character array that I want to `sort`. The issue is if I pass the array as it is to the `sort` function than it actually converts the array characters which are actually numbers in their ASCII equivalents. For e.g. 4 become 52.

```
std::vector<int> classStudents;
....
char* cend = cAllowedStudents+maxAllowedStudents;
std::sort(cAllowedStudents, cend);
std::set_difference(classStudents.begin(), classStudents.end(),cAllowedStudents, cend,std::back_inserter(diff));
```

I also tried converting the whole array into separate `int` array through this, (however ideally I don’t want to use another array but only as a last choice):

```
iAllowedStudents[i]=(int)cAllowedStudents[i];
```

But it also does the same, so how can I convert this `cAllowedStudents` to be used with `std::set_difference`

Comment: what is the type of `classStudents`?

Comment: Numbers and their ASCII equivalents have the same sort order - what is the actual problem ? Are there non-numeric characters in the data ?

Comment: How about accepting one of the answers for [the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134221/compare-element-in-a-vector-with-elements-in-an-array) you posted on this yesterday?

Comment: How should comparing work during sorting? Is `'a' < '4'` or `'a' > '4'`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, why would you compare an array of ints with an array of chars? What is the information in the character sequence that is of interest? Maybe if you added an example, that would be a little clearer... as it stands, voting to close..

Comment: @Nim `classStudents` is of `std::vector<int>` type.

Comment: @PaulR There are no non-numeric characters but i need an array of numbers so i can use `set_difference` on both data structures containing numbers.

Comment: @legends2k If you look there closely, my last comments still hasnt been answered, about the conversion, right?

Comment: @Maven no, I see all your comments answered; actually [you didn't answers comments on clarifying the question further](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134221/compare-element-in-a-vector-with-elements-in-an-array#comment37238466_24134221), and you expect answers :)

Comment: @legends2k i dont what are you seeing. My last comment over `R Sahu` answer still unanswered, refresh your browser or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

and pass a custom comparison function